# Disabling QuickType into my html form fields

Tags: keyboard, safari, ios, html

I'm creating several html forms.

People asked me to remove the **QuickType** functionality introduced with iOS 8 for some of those forms fields cause sometime it's irrevelant and use screen place for nothing.

It's seems **QuickType** only appears for `<input type="text">`.

Even it has not been designed for that, I tried the `autocomplete="off"` and it doesn't work without a surprise.

I don't want to globaly desactivate **QuickType** into the parameters or to temporary hide it with a **swipe down**.

PS : **QuickType** is not yet a tag, I propose to add it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's answered [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26187942/2062591):

> i put `autocapitalize="off"` `autocomplete="off"` `autocorrect="off"`
>
> and it works.

The asker said `autocapitalize="off"` was not needed.